# What's wrong with this tiny program?

Tags: c, while-loop

```
void main(){
/* This string needs to be printed without the '%' and in segments. */
    char str[] = "Oct: %o Dec: %d Roman: %r"; 
    int i = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0'){ 

/* When I run this nested loops, for some reason they don't stop at '\0'. */

        while (str[i] != '%'){
            printf("%c", str[i++]);
        }
        if (str[i] == '%')
            i++;
    }    
}
```

Comment: `while (str[i] != '%')` will skip over the `\0`.

Comment: Why would you expect the inner loop to stop at `\0`?

Comment: Oh and don't forget `void main()` is bad. Use `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: @tangrs Since this is C it should be `int main(void)`

Comment: Both should work but `int main(void)` is nicer and will avoid some warnings on pedantic compilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to print all characters in the string, omitting any `%` characters. You don't need an inner loop for that, and that inner loop is the cause of all your woes. The inner loop will run beyond the end of the string because it does not test for the null terminating character.

The simple solution is to replace the inner loop with an `if` statement. The idea is to iterate across the entire string, and print any characters that are not `%`.

```
int i = 0;
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if (str[i] != '%')
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Although I'd probably write this using pointers:

```
const char *p = str;
while (*p)
{
    if (*p != '%')
        printf("%c", *p);
    p++;
}
```

---

As an aside, your `main` function has a non-standard declaration. For a C `main` which does not wish to process arguments your main should be:

```
int main(void)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that once you get to here:

```
 Oct: %o Dec: %d Roman: %r
                         ^
```

The inner while loop will just keep spinning forever (you can verify that by removing the `r`, it will stop as it should).

To fix this you can replace the `while (str[i] != '%')` with `if (str[i] != '%')` and you won't have to touch the original string.

A few more comments:

Change the return type of `main` from `void` to `int`. And add `return 0;` just before the closing brace of `main`. This is a typical C convention which indicates to the OS if the run was successful (0 means OK, non-zero means there was a problem).

If you compile your code with warnings you should have got a warning for it (do enable them as some bugs are not always so obvious and warnings do a great job of informing you for them).

With my GCC compiler I got `warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]`. I run it with the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags.

Comment: Your point about warnings is a good one. I tend to recommend running `clang` or `gcc` with `-Wall -Werror`.

Comment: Thanks, will add that to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

that while will skip over the '\0' since it is not a '%'

Answer (score 0):

@BryanOlivier is right, so

```
while ((str[i] != '%')&&(str[i] != '\0')){
        printf("%c", str[i++]);
    }
```

instead of

```
 while (str[i] != '%'){
        printf("%c", str[i++]);
    }
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead -->

```
   while (str[i] != '\0'){ 
        if(str[i++] != '%') {
            printf("%c", str[i])
        }
        else {

        }
}
```